# Search Numbers spreadsheet for \n

Tags: mac, numbers, search

If I search for "\n" in a Numbers spreadsheet, it only shows me any cells that have line breaks in them, it does not show me cells that have "\n" written in them.

Is there any way to search for \n?

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming **\n** is literal. you'll just have to search for a _backslash_ instead.

Answer (score -1):

Literal "\n" a blackslash with the character 'n' is different from a newline character.  I was able to search for newline characters by pressing Option + Return but that didn't find literal "\n" in cells but it did find newlines when I inserted them with Option + Return in cells.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this re-states the same issue I was describing. I can find newlines but I can't find the \n in the cells, as shown in the screenshot you added